# JestJs not awaiting call wrapping async/await

Tags: typescript, async-await, jestjs

I have the following class:

```
import * as request from "request-promise-native";
export class publisher {

  publish(file : string) : PublisherResponse{

     let response = PublisherResponse.EmptyResponse;
     let options = {};
     let promise = this.executeRequest(file , options);
     promise.then( value =>  response = value );

     return response;
  }

  async executeRequest(file : string, options : any ) : Promise<PublisherResponse>{
     let promise = await request.get("http://someAPI", options);
     console.debug("we need to wait for this thing to finish ...")
     let response = await promise; 
     let data = response.data;

    return new new PublisherResponse(file, data);

 }
}
```

The Jest test is as follows:

```
test('Should publish a valid single document', async () => {

      // Arrange
      var documentToPublish = "file1.oas3";

      let sut = new publisher(); 
      let expectedResponse = new PublisherResponse(documentToPublish, "some-data");

      // Act
      let actualResponse = sut.publish(documentToPublish);   

      // Assert
    expect(actualResponse).toEqual(expectedResponse);
    });
```

The test fails because execution does not appear to stop in the async method executeRequest until the awaitable lines have been completed.

What I end up getting is an error indicating that

> Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something
>   async in your test?
>       Attempted to log "we need to wait for this thing to finish ...".

I'll prefer not to make the publish API return a promise for now if I can get away with this.   Any ideas on what I could be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The test fails because execution does not appear to stop in the `async` method `executeRequest` until the awaitable lines have been completed.

You are absolutely right. Execution does not stop in the `async` method; instead, *execution returns to the caller until the Promise completes*. Here is what happens:

1. `jest` calls `publish`
2. `publish` calls `executeRequest`
3. `executeRequest` calls `await request.get...`
4. `executeRequest` returns control to `publish`
5. `publish` returns control to `jest`
6. `jest` runs its expectation
7. `await request.get...` returns
8. `executeRequest` calls `console.log...`
9. jest complains :-(

This is the way `async`/`await` (and `Promise`/`then`) works.

> I'll prefer not to make the publish API return a promise for now if I can get away with this. Any ideas on what I could be missing here?

My suggestion: don't try to get away with calling an async function from a synchronous function. Instead, have `publish` return a `Promise`. Any code that wants `publish` to be fire-and-forget can choose not to wait for the `Promise`.

That would change your code to something like this:

```
export class publisher {

  async publish(file: string): Promise<PublisherResponse> {
     let response = PublisherResponse.EmptyResponse;
     let options = {};
     let promise = this.executeRequest(file , options);
     await promise.then(value => response = value); // return control to caller
     return response;
  }

  async executeRequest(file: string, options: any): Promise<PublisherResponse> {
     let promise = request.get("http://someAPI", options);
     console.debug("we need to wait for this thing to finish ...")
     let response = await promise; // return control to caller
     let data = response.data;
     return new new PublisherResponse(file, data);
  }
}

test('Should publish a valid single document', async () => {
  // Arrange
  var documentToPublish = "file1.oas3";

  let sut = new publisher(); 
  let expectedResponse = new PublisherResponse(documentToPublish, "some-data");

  // Act (return control to caller)
  let actualResponse = await sut.publish(documentToPublish);   

  // Assert
  expect(actualResponse).toEqual(expectedResponse);
});
```

Comment: Well explained sir, thank you. Ended up changing the publish to return a promise which propagated upstream.  Easier to fix my code to confirm than fight with the framework.